# Laravel Socialite: Saving new User in DB

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working with Laravel Socialite and a User should be able to login with Github, Twitter and the normal Way. I did the Authentication NOT with `php artisan make:auth` because I want to do it by myself. So I called the Model `Username` and not `User` (like normal).

The Problem is that the User does not get stored in my Database. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is my function:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider){

        $socialize_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        $social_user_id = $socialize_user->getId();


        $user = Username::where('provider_id', $social_user_id)->first();

        //register if no user
        if(!$user){
            $user = new Username();
            $user->name = $socialize_user->getName();
            $user->email = $socialize_user->getEmail();
            $user->provider_id = $social_user_id;
            $user->save();
        }

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect('to_dos');

    }
```

**EDIT:**
The Username Model:

```
class Username extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /*
     * Database table used by model.
     *
     */
    protected $table = 'usernames';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'provider_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

It seems everything is working fine, but If i'm taking a look in my database, there is no new entry. Hope anyone of you knows how to do it right.

Comment: Could you post your `Username` model? Also, does creating a Username through Eloquent work on Artisan Tinker? Perhaps, there's an error in the configuration of your model (e.g. table name, connection, etc.)

Comment: @Paras I added the Username model. And if I create a new User with the "normal" login, everything is saved in my database.

Comment: Checked your code, everything feels fine. Only thing is that you missed adding the provider where clause like so: `$user = Username::where('provider_id', $social_user_id)->where('provider', $provider)->first();` in case you're using multiple providers. But I doubt this is the source of your error.

Comment: Try dropping the brackets at  `$user = new Username();` so it should be `$user = new Username;` as Username is a model and not a function.

Comment: Do you have auth.php inside your config?  If you do you can update your user model to whatever you want.

Comment: @Paras, @just_chris @usrNotFound: Thanks for your response and thougths. I changed from `$user = new Username;` to `Username::create([$myvariables]);`. Now everything works properly.